# Redirect a url that has a previous redirect match set up

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a url that has been indexed but it 404s. This url is also used for other parts of the site.

e.g. `www.example.com/events/event` => 404s

e.g. `www.example.com/events/event/THIS-IS-A-GREAT-EVENT` is a proper url

There is a RedirectMatch in the htaccess to match the old url structure and it is using a wildcard:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/events/(?!(?:event/|P\d|category|featured|post|rss|test))(.*)$ www.example.com/events/event/$1`

Because of this I am unable to use a proper redirect for the `www.example.com/events/event` to redirect to `www.example.com/events`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert new rule **above** your existing rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/events/event/?$ /events

RedirectMatch 301 ^/events/(?!(?:event/|P\d|category|featured|post|rss|test))(.*)$ /events/event/$1
```